# Nested function in Bash: why does return stop parent function?

Tags: bash

```
function test_ok {
  echo "function without error" || { echo "[Error] text"; return 1; }
  echo "this is executed"
}
function test_nok {
  echo "function with error"
  cause-an-error || { echo "[Error] text"; return 1; }
  echo "this is not executed"
  echo "this is not executed"
}
test_ok ; echo "$?"
test_nok ; echo "$?"
```

I would expect that the `return 1` in function `test_nok` only exits the nested function `{ echo "[Error] text"; return 1; }` and the following two echo commands are executed as they belong to the parent function `test_nok`.

But that's not true, `echo "this is not executed"` really is not executed and the exit code of `test_nok` is 1. This is the behavior I need, but I do not understand why it works that way => why is `echo "this is not executed"` not executed?

Comment: There's no nested function here. `{ }`isn't a function, it just groups commands.

Comment: Thank you Gordon Davisson, that answers my question. But I think I cannot mark a comment as the solution, right?

Comment: If you only want to return from the *"nested function"* then use a subshell `(...)` instead of a group `{...}`.

Answer (score 1):

[Gordon Davisson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/89817/gordon-davisson) answered my question in a comment:

There's no nested function here. `{ }` isn't a function, it just groups commands.

Comment: That was my intention, but I get the message "You can accept your own answer in 2 days". So I will accept it in 2 days or Gordon Davisson could write an answer that I can accept

Answer (score 0):

You could save the error code in a variable and return it at the end of the function (though this may not a good idea. i'd recommend to return when the error occurs) :

```
function test_nok {
    echo "function with error"
    cause-an-error || { error_code=$?; echo "[Error] text"; }
    echo "this is not executed"
    echo "this is not executed"
    return $error_code
}
test_nok
echo $?
```

Output:

```
function with error
./test.sh: line 5: cause-an-error: command not found
[Error] text
this is not executed
this is not executed
127
```

Comment: Thank you. My posted code works like I need it, I just didn't understand why. But I think Gordon Davisson just answered my question => {} is not a function

Comment: Good, and regarding your question `why is echo "this is not executed" not executed?`  you may want to read more about the `{ ...; }` command in bash documentation: section of [group command](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html)

Comment: Thank you Sergio, that's just what I did the last few minutes :-)